# Can you help me fix my code for my IR detection/emitting/project

Tags: testing, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++, infrared

**Context:** Hello wonderful people of stack overflow, I am currently very lost with my arduino project. In short, I have a school project and I'm trying to make an arduino uno powered glove that essentially using a screen and software ill be able to select custom presets of devices I can control using specific gestures i do with my glove. For example, i select on my screen tv mode and it'll set the glove to tv mode where for example with I pinch my finger I can turn on the tv, pinch my ring finger and it'll switch channels, etc.

**THE PROBLEM:** i have a problem with my code. I keep getting the FFFFFFFF code and I want it to be more specific, do you know how to do that?

**my code:**

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv Irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  IrReceiver.enableIRIn();
}

void loop() {
  if (IrReceiver.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    IrReceiver.resume();
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

**Materials List:**
Glove Components:

Flex Sensors (5 x $7.00) - $59.75

IR Components:

IR Transmitter - $0.30

IR Receiver - $1.00

Arduino Uno- $23.00

Other Components:

Transistor (BC547) - $0.20

Jumper Wires - $8.29

Power Supply:

Batteries and Connectors - $28.97

Miscellaneous:

Resistors and breadboard - $20.00

Comment: To rule out an issue with your components, try completely covering the IR receiver to block all light. If it still triggers, then you have either a faulty component, incorrect wiring, or your code is acting strange, or it's something weird like thermals. If it stops triggering, you know that the source is probably external. There is IR light everywhere. You may want to add some filtering that discards noisy signals, such as a pulse that's significantly too long or short. You'll need to run some experiments to try and isolate and understand the problem before attempting to fix it.

Comment: so it ended up being my ir receiver probably messed up but now i have a problem with my code. I keep getting the FFFFFFFF code and I want it to be more specufic, do you know how to do that?
code:
'''
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv Irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  IrReceiver.enableIRIn();
}

void loop() {
  if (IrReceiver.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    IrReceiver.resume();
  }
  delay(100);
}
'''
THE CODE IS WEIRD AS A COMMENT SO I EDITED THE ORIGINAL QUESTION TY

Comment: I'd start by reading the documentation: https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote